# How does Jeepers Creepers 3 fit in to the timeline?

Tags: jeepers-creepers

It says in the franchise that every 23 years it returns and eat for 23 days, if I am right first two parts happen in different time periods. Then when did the third film exactly took place ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**tl;dr**

[Jeepers Creepers 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeepers_Creepers_3) takes place in between [Jeepers Creepers (2001)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeepers_Creepers_(2001_film)) and [Jeepers Creepers 2 (2003)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeepers_Creepers_2)

[**“Jeepers Creepers 3” Chronology, Connections & Ending Explained**](http://horrorfreaknews.com/spoilers-jeepers-creepers-3-chronology-connections-ending-explained)

**Warning: Below There Be Spoilers!**

> Despite being the third chapter in the franchise, **Jeepers Creepers 3** takes place in the 4 days in between **Jeepers Creepers (2001)** and **Jeepers Creepers 2 (2003)**.
>
> **Jeepers Creepers 3** does, however, contain one flashback scene and one flash-forward. Jeepers Creepers 2 also ends with a flash-forward. Here’s how the action would unfold if every Jeepers Creepers film was arranged chronologically.
>
> - 1978: Intro/Flashback from Jeepers Creepers 3.
> - 2001: Jeepers Creepers (Days 1-2)
> - 2001: Jeepers Creepers 3 (Days 2-5)
> - 2001: Jeepers Creepers 2 (Days 5-6)
> - Unknown Future: Trish (Gina Phillips) Outro from Jeepers Creepers 3
> - 2024: Jeepers Creepers 2 final scene.

But I see a mistake here, The Jeepers Creepers 2 takes places in 22<sup>nd</sup> and 23<sup>rd</sup> day of feeding. 
 <sub>[reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeepers_Creepers_2)</sub>

So the timeline could be like this :

- 2001: Jeepers Creepers (Days 1-2)
- 2001: Jeepers Creepers 3 (Days 2-5)
- 2001: Jeepers Creepers 2 (Days 22-23)

> **Connections**
>
> *Meg Foster* plays a grieving mother named **Gaylen Brandon**; she’s haunted by the ghost of her dead son who was one of The Creeper’s victims **in 1978**. His name is **Kenny Brandon** (played by Jordan Salloum) and if his name sounds familiar, there’s a reason.
>
> When **Darry** (Justin Long) and **Trish** (Gina Phillips) are driving down a Florida highway before being attacked by The Creeper (Jonathan Breck) they discuss the urban legend of **Darla and Kenny**, an interracial couple who disappeared on Prom Night back **in 1978**.
>
> Authorities found **Kenny’s** car wrecked on the side of the road but both bodies were missing—except for **Darla’s decapitated head**.
>
> **Darry** would actually see **Kenny and Darla’s corpses** when he investigated The Creepers lair beneath the church.
>
> The **“Creeper Hunters”** led by Sheriff Tashtego (Stan Shaw) have all lost relatives to Creeper attacks, but none of them appeared in previous films.
>
> **Ending Explained**
>
> **Jeepers Creepers 3** ends with The Creeper being bested by the film’s heroes; he screams in defeat as dead crows fall from the sky all around them. The key seems to be knowing the truth about the creature’s origins, for it’s when he reads a sign left by **Gaylen Brandon** (Foster) that reads **“We know what you are”** that the fiend gives up his chase.
>
> We know The Creeper isn’t killed by this revelation, as he goes on to terrorize the **kids on the bus** (Jeepers Creepers 2), but it scares him enough to leave his current targets alone. This suggests that knowledge of The Creeper’s roots is essential to destroying the creature once and for all.
>
> The penultimate scene shows **Buddy Hooks** (played by Chester Rushing) getting on a bus, bound for a **high school championship baseball game**; this is just hours before the events of **Jeepers Creepers 2**, although Buddy is not a character specifically introduced/portrayed in that film.

Again a mistake, This scene was occurred on the 5th day, that is why Buddy is not in Jeepers Creepers 2. May be they dropped him home on 22nd day or maybe he was absent.

> The final scene of **Trish** (Gina Phillips) narrating her story in front of a computer screen is an unknown point in the future; this is **after the events of Jeepers Creepers 2** but before the creature’s reemergence **in 2024**.

Comment: I thought Jeepers Creepers and Jeepers Creepers 2 set in different years, thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 1):

At the beginning of Jeepers Creepers 2 it says “DAY 23”.

In Jeepers Creepers 2, while the kids are on the school bus, on the radio the news is talking about the church fire from Jeepers Creepers 1, saying the fire started 4 days before.

Then when watching Jeepers Creepers 3 it starts where the end of jJeepers Creepers 1 ended and ends where Jeepers Creepers 2 starts.

So according to the movies the timeline is :

**DAY 19& morning of 20** - Jeepers Creepers 1.

**DAY 20,21,22 & morning of 23** -Jeepers Creepers 3.

**DAY 23** - Jeepers Creepers 2